# Google Cloud Storage Document Thumbnail Image?

Tags: php, drupal, google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client

We are needing to grab a thumbnail image of our documents on Google Could Storage for use in our Drupal module. Previously https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=DOC_STORAGE_URL&a=bi&pagenumber=1 worked for us, but the google viewer seems to no longer support the a=bi parameter.

Does anyone have any information about the viewer no longer generating a thumbnail, or know if there is a way to grab a thumbnail image of the document stored on Google Could Storage using its API like you can with the Drive API? We are currently using the google-api-php-client.
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Storage does not generate thumbnails for any objects. You would need to generate these thumbnails, upload them to Google Cloud Storage, and then reference them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As @rein said, GCS doesn't generate thumbnails for any object. But there is an alternative: the Images API. Although is not available for PHP, if you can write in Python [1] or JAVA [2] this library contains the functionality you are looking for.

Check the function `get_serving_url` here [3]. It will generate an url that accepts parameters. Specifically, the parameter `=sXX` will generates thumbnails of XX pixels (on the longest dimension).

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/

[2] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/

[3] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions